# Assignments for arrays of pointers to structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Currently I'm working on a **C** project to do basic simulation of CPU scheduling algorithms on an arbitrary number of sudo processes (with some of their attributes) given through an input .txt file.

I want to create an array of structs for the processes and a queue that is an array of pointers to these structs. With my knowledge of C pointers I believe that I can create and assign the array of pointers in this way but every time I look up online how to do this I find a different explanation. Here is my code for the structs and pointers:

```
struct Process
{
    int id;
    int arrival;
    int burst;
    int priority;
};


int main()
{
    //create array of Process(es) from input.txt
    //numProcesses is obtained from parsing input.txt
    struct Process processes[numProcesses];

    //create ready queue for CPU scheduling
    struct Process* fifoQueue[numProcesses];

    //assume processes[] is filled here with info from input.txt

    //loop through processes[] adding entries to the queue
    for(i=0; i < numProcesses; i++)
    {
        //this is what I am confused about
        fifoQueue[i] = &processes[i];
    } 
}
```

Is it possible to use `fifoQueue[i] = &processes[i];` to initialize the queue or do I have to do some malloc() magic?

Comment: Do you mean *pseudo-processes*? `sudo` is a Linux command.

Comment: What you've written is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you are using the C89 C standard when compiling your program. C89 requires all array sizes to be able to be determined at compile time, but C99 and onward removed this limitation. If you are using C89, then you will have to use `malloc` to allocate the array, otherwise, what you have is fine.